# What is represented by this notation of an inequality between a matrix and scalar

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, notation

In theorem 3.2 of [this paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0024379505002284/1-s2.0-S0024379505002284-main.pdf?_tid=a9b66b97-ea4e-4e25-a1d4-4408b7d4d825&acdnat=1521308596_71b6f961d7330a6c38da7cd249ef4690), the following statement is made:

$$\sigma_n(M - \lambda_1 I) \leq \Vert \Delta M \Vert_2$$

where $\sigma_n$ is the smallest singular value of $M$.

What does this mean? The left hand side appears to be a matrix, and the right hand side is a scalar. How can these be compared?

Comment: The left hand side is the smallest singular value of its argument, which is a non negative real number.

Comment: Ah! I was reading $\sigma_n$ as a value that was being multiplied by the contents of the parentheses. Thanks

Comment: Replace "where $\sigma_n$ is the smallest singular value of $M$" by "where, for every matrix $A$, $\sigma_n(A)$ is the smallest singular value of $A$".